# Toast не выводит русские символы

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня в основной активити заменяются разные фрагменты. В одних Toast выводится нормально, в других русский выводит в виде ? в треугольнике.

Как такое может быть? Помогите. Голову сломал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измените кодировку файла на UTF-8. Вероятно, там где нормально, строковые ресурсы подтягиваются из string.xml, который всегда UTF-8.

Comment: Да спасибо!!! Использование строкового ресурса проблему решило. Но я ни где в остальных фрагментах не использовал строковые ресурсы для Toast

Comment: Как-то можно изменить кодировку только для одного файла? Я думал это свойство меняется для всей IDEA(Android Studio) или проэкта

Comment: @BogdanShulga, В Intelij IDEA (вероятно и в студии) в правом нижнем углу меняется кодировка файла

Comment: Странно но у меня в обоих IDEA в правом нижнем углу только Event Log хотя должно быть помню. Где-то скрыта панель. Буду искать спасибо.

Comment: Status Bar называется :) Нашел.